# Can "popular" also be a noun?

Tags: nouns, nominalization

From the movie [Geek Charming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geek_Charming):

> OK, guys, seriously, it's a whole other alien world. A mystery species. We'll never fully understand the **populars** and the way their strange vortex works.

This line obviously uses "popular" as a noun meaning "popular kids". And no dictionary seems to support this usage. (I'd like to add this usage also is dissimilar to "the poor" where the definite article in conjunction with an adjective means a group in general.) Is it a common usage or is this nominalization highly rare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In informal or slang speech, native English speakers will often use a word that should be one grammatical part of speech as another.  The most well-known example of this is [verbing](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-verbing/), which is the practice of using a noun (like **verb**) as a verb (by conjugating it with -ing).

Your example is using an adjective as a noun.  In particular, it's using an adjective describing a group of people as a noun labeling this group.  This deliberate grammatical error has the rhetorical effect of ironically distancing the speaker from that group.  That is, **"the populars"** are so distant and alien to the speaker that he or she can't even see them as individuals: they are only comprehensible as [avatars](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avatar) of the quality of being popular.

You correctly contrast this with the noun "the poor," which is not used in this same ironic sense.  However, you'll find that Urban Dictionary has an entry for **["the poors"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=The%20poors)**, which *is* exactly parallel to the use of "the populars" in your example (Urban Dictionary is not always a reliable source, but I can confirm that I have seen "the poors" used in informal writing on the internet).  It has the same sense of ironic detachment: someone using "the poors" is doing so to emphasize that they are stereotyping all poor people and not seeing them as individuals.